# Django ForeignKey reverse Query

Tags: django, django-templates

I have 3 models related witch each other with FK:

```
class MainEvent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    main_event = models.ForeignKey(MainEvent, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=512, blank=True)

class SubEvent(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

What i need is to create single reverse query on model MainEvent that holds related Events and Subevents. I will use this with Q for filter multiple options.

For example:

there are 2 MainEvents, each of them have 2 or more Events and each Event have 2 or more Subevents. 
I'm trying to create single Query something like this:

```
 [MainEvent_1:[Event_1:[Subevent_1,Subevent_2,...],Event_2:[Subevent_5,...]], MainEvent_2:[Event_2:[Subevent_2,..]]]
```

For now I'm creating dictionary that holds desired output, but with this i con't use Q relations like & or |.

At the end i'm using this data in template table to show all events and filter them:

desired table structure:

```
main event_1:
event_1:
subevent_1
subevent_2
event_2:
subev...
...........
main event_2:
event_2:
subev....
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MainEvent.objects.filter(Q(event__subevent__done=True) | Q(event__subevent__done=False))
```

you can use something like this and then access the sub events using `.` inside loop

```
for item in query:
    for i in item.event_set.all():
        for j in i.subevent_set.all():
            print(i.name)
            print(j.done)
```

Comment: with this i can only access MainEvent fields

Comment: no you can access with `.event` and `.event.subevent` for those models fields

Comment: when i loop over query: for item in query: item.event, then i get error:  
'MainEvent' object has no attribute 'event'

Comment: check the edited ans, how you are going to access it

Comment: ok looping is working but i need to loop over this query in template, and display elements like this: 1 row: main event data, next few rows: related events data, next few rows related subevents data, then next main event data and so on ...

Comment: yeah it will be same in the template also. same looping technique

Comment: i know the technique but this looping will generating number of MainEvents equal to number of SubEvents, and i need only few MainEvents that contains few Events that contains few SubEvents

Comment: use that query in the view as i have given at top, filter according what you need then send it to template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201605/discussion-between-zaraki-kenpachi-and-exprator).

Comment: at the end You solution was good, one element what is missing was .distinct() at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in one query, but you can do it in three queries using `prefetch_related()`:

```
MainEvent.objects.prefetch_related('event_set', 'event_set__subevent_set').all()
```

If all of your `MainEvents` have `Events` and all of your `Events` have `SubEvents`, you could do it in one query by starting from `SubEvents` and doing the grouping in code:

```
SubEvent.objects.select_related('event', 'event__main_event').all()
```

Comment: this give the same result as : SubEvent.objects.all(). Is there a possibility to filter MainEvent Query by its fields and event fields?